# Why i can not connect myself as root on mac using the terminal?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, root

Actually i have to connect myself as an admin :

```
ssh user@xxx.xxx.xx.xx to log into the mac and then use "su" to be as root.
```

I can't connect myself directly as root!
*WHY?!?...*.

Answer (score 0):

You have got to edit `/private/etc/sshd_config` and remove the comment on the line:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

As well as having an active root account (which I suppose you already do.)

EDIT:

You should then uncomment this line **on the server**, probably at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and  restart sshd using `/etc/rc.d/sshd restart`.

For the sake of security, though, I would recommend you against this practice and in favor of using `su` or `sudo` instead once connected.

Comment: EH ! Thanks for your answer, but i didn't find the correct file :/

Comment: Which version of OSX have you installed? It's kind of weird that you can't find that file, since its a unix standard. Take a look at `/etc/sshd_config`, just in case.

Comment: Sorry I didn't precise ! Im trying to connect from My on 10.6.8 to a FreeBSD 8.3 machine